# Data validation (Not Spring @Annotation) before insert or update via native SQL?

Tags: java

We don't need spring @annotation which takes care of the validation of the column values or error messages.

Do we have any non-spring specific data validation before insert/update on a plain native SQL?

Implementing Jrule would be heavy. Looking for some simple library or classes which does it

Example

```
if(String.isBlank(usr.getEmail)) {
   // register error
}
```

etc., for each and every field for every table
Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code examples?

Comment: pls check the above

Comment: You can try to use base Java validation Api - JSR 380 using `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator`. Have a look at this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

Comment: But we are not using hibernate and we are using plain native SQL to inser/update/delete

Comment: You can use the Hibernate validation annotations, even if you are not using Hibernate.

Comment: @Leander will that creates any overload because Hibernate would have lots of jars or should i include only the respective jar in the pom.xml